# How to get and print mp3 Popularimeter frame with golang id3-go library

Tags: go, id3, id3v2

I would like to read the Popularimeter frame from a file with [id3-go](https://github.com/mikkyang/id3-go).

This is how the frame looks like when printing with [mutagen-inspect](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mutagen-inspect.html):

```
$ mutagen-inspect samples/with_popm.mp3 | grep POPM
POPM=traktor@native-instruments.de=0 255/255
```

I would like to read the value (255/255) from the file. As I could not find any documentation, my naive approach is:

```
popFrame := mp3File.Frame("POPM")
log.Println(popFrame.String())
```

But when I run this (on a file with and also without a popularimeter tag), I get segmentation faults:

```
$ ./id3-go-popm-example samples/with_popm.mp3 
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x4ac302]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/ifischer/src/rivamp/rivamp-dist/id3-go-popm-example/main.go:21 +0xd2
$ ./id3-go-popm-example samples/without_popm.mp3 
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x4ac302]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /home/ifischer/src/rivamp/rivamp-dist/id3-go-popm-example/main.go:21 +0xd2
```

I setup a sample repository containing two sample files (one with, one without popularimeter frame) here: https://github.com/ifischer/id3-go-popm-example

How to I get the Popularimeter value (255/255) with id3-go library?

Comment: The actual segfault/backtrace could also be helpful.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi updated question with segfault

Comment: I just finished inspecting the id3-go library, it's definitely issue on the 3rd party it self. the possible solution are: 1. fix the issue on id3-go; 2. or just use another library, like @ssemilla's answer

Comment: I've added the fix if you really need to use `id3-go`, it's a one-liner fix since it is just missing the `TDRC` field.

Comment: I've also added the code snippet to parse the popularimeter as it seems not to be included in `id3-go`. I hope this already answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting a segmentation fault because `mp3File.Frame("POPM")` is actually returning a `nil` value. I've narrowed it down to the `V23FrameTypeMap` in `id3-go` which lacks the `TRDC` frame. I'm really not familiar with the internals of ID3 but maybe you need to check if `TRDC` is really in V2.3 and if it is, add the missing ids in `V23FrameTypeMap` in `id3-go`.

Since it would be too much of a hassle to learn ID3, I've managed to get the `POPM` tag using another library https://github.com/dhowden/tag

```
f, _ := os.Open("with_popm.mp3")
m, _ := tag.ReadFrom(f)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", m.Raw()["POPM"])
```

which outputs:

```
traktor@native-instruments.de
```

Edit: I mistook `TDRC` as `TRDC`, my mistake. Anyway, here is what you need to do to get the `POPM` field using `id3-go`

Add the following in `V23FrameTypeMap` in `github.com/mikkyang/id3-go/v2/idv23.go`

```
V23FrameTypeMap = map[string]FrameType{
    //...
    "TDRC": FrameType{id: "TDRC", description: "Recording Date", constructor: ParseTextFrame},
}
```

Then you can easily get the `POPM` field e.g.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    id3 "github.com/mikkyang/id3-go"
)

func main() {

    f, _ := id3.Open("with_popm.mp3")
    p := f.Frame("POPM")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", p.Bytes())

}
```

Edit 2: I've added a way so that you can parse the `POPM` field. You can then access the rating 255/255 from `Popularimeter.Rating`:

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    id3 "github.com/mikkyang/id3-go"
)

func main() {

    f, _ := id3.Open("with_popm.mp3")
    popm := f.Frame("POPM")
    popularimeter, _ := FromData(popm.Bytes())
    fmt.Println(popularimeter)
}

type Rating uint8

func (r Rating) String() string {
    if r == 0 {
        return "unknown"
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d/255", r)
}

type Popularimeter struct {
    Email   string
    Rating  Rating
    Counter uint32
}

func FromData(data []byte) (*Popularimeter, error) {

    tokens := bytes.SplitN(data, []byte{0x0}, 2)
    // Pupolarimeter: <string>, null, 1byte rating, 4bytes counter
    if len(tokens) != 2 || len(tokens[1]) != 5 {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid Popularimeter")
    }

    return &Popularimeter{
        Email:   string(tokens[0]),
        Rating:  Rating(tokens[1][0]),
        Counter: binary.BigEndian.Uint32(tokens[1][1:]),
    }, nil
}
```

Comment: Answer deserves bounty especially for explanation! However using id3-go would be preferred as it can also modify ID3 tags

Comment: I was very sleepy last night and I mistook TDRC as TRDC. Anyway, the answer is edited so you can parse POPM using `id3-go`